# How to restore a Cold Backup of Oracle Database to new environment

Tags: oracle, backup, restore

All of a sudden my laptop ran into a problem and the sfc command ruined the whole thing and couldn't boot my Windows 10. Due to this, I formatted the laptop and now I want to restore the Oracle 11g Standard Edition One database from my old laptop to new laptop. Here is the procedure how to do the restore and I tested it in my laptop and works absolutely fine.

This is the simplest and easiest way of restoring the oracle database in case you ran into a problem with your laptop or server.

Answer (score 0):

Restoring the Database Procedure

First install the same version of Oracle 11g database with the default oracle database name as ORCL in the same path as your old laptop. Connect to sqlplus and make sure you are able to connect to database.

Sqlplus / as sysdba

Shutdown the database before you proceed further.

Shutdown immediate

Old Laptop setup:

C:\app\leslin\oradata\orcl
C:\app\mlesl\oradata\orcl

New Laptop Setup:

C:\app\leslin\oradata\orcl
C:\app\hp\oradata\orcl

Do not touch the files under C:\app\hp\oradata\orcl

1. Copy all the DBF files in the exact location in the New Laptop except the C:\app\hp\oradata\orcl folder (New Laptop installed folder)
2. Create the exact folder of old Laptop eg: C:\app\leslin\oradata\orcl

   step 2 is required if the folder path of new Laptop is different.
3. Copy the Control file (CONTROL01.CTL) file from the original location (C:\app\mlesl\oradata\orcl) of old Laptop to the following places in new Laptop.

   C:\app\leslin\oradata\orcl

   C:\app\hp\oradata\orcl

   C:\app\hp\flash_recovery_area\orcl (Rename the file as CONTROL02.CTL)
4. Sqlplus / as sysdba
5. Startup

   (there is no need to issue Startup mount and recover database commands)

All databases, users, tablespaces and everything will be in place.

Answer (score 0):

(Old thread, I know, but this needs to be countered).

I would suggest that you were *lucky* and that your database was lightly-loaded (or even quiescent) when your unfortunate "event" happened.

The best (and recommended and only officially *supported*) way to *restore* an Oracle database is to use the **Backups** that you take precisely (and, quite often, *only*) for this purpose.

Your method is akin to crashing your car, at speed, into a brick wall and then trying to get into it and drive off again.  You have *no idea* what state any of the Data Files - or, worse, the Control Files - are in.  What you "restore" might not even start or might be "missing" huge chunks of Data.

Take the time to learn about RMAN and how it can save your job.